# Passing multiple query objects with res.render

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to pass multiple query objects with `res.render()` inside my `route.js`. I have a `select.js` which contains the SQL statements and delivers the objects to my route.js. This works fine until I want to pass multiple query objects with `res.render()`.
Any ideas on how I can pass multiple objects at once?

snippet route.js (I need to pass get_PriceData here as well)

I already query get_KategorieData but I have no clue how to handle multiple queries in one route.

```
router.get('/edit', (req, res, next) => {
  var speisenEintragenData = {};
  db.get_KategorieData()
    .then(({ data: kategorie_data }) => {
      res.render('speiseEintragen', { kategorie_data }); //maybe putting res.render() after the db.get?
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

select.js

```
const db = require('./config');

//KATEGORIEN LADEN
const get_KategorieData=()=>{
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM Kategorie';
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    db.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({data});
    });
  })
}

//PREISE LADEN

const get_PriceData=()=>{
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM preise';
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    db.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve({data});
    });
  })
}

module.exports={
  get_KategorieData,
  get_PriceData
}
```

Comment: this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52245174/render-multiple-queries-in-node-express/52251587

Comment: Yeah I found this post as well but I use this querys in different routes individualy. If there is no possible solution inside my route.js I can try implementing a new own combined query for this particular site

Comment: hmm yeah if I was you maybe I would be looking at SQL joins, see if i can write an SQL query which joins both Kategorie and Preise. Although I don't know your DB schema so  not sure if thats possible for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to go about this. One is to stick with promises and other is to use async/await.
Using promise
Create a new function to query database. This is if the module you are using does not support async/await and requires a callback.

```
const query = ( sql ) => {
  return new Promise(( resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, function (err, data, fields) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(data);
    });
  })
}
// and then you can write an async/await function to call n queries like
const get_data = async () => {
  const sql1 = '...';
  const a = await query( sql1 );
  const sql2 = '...';
  const b = await query( sql2 );
  ....
  ....
  ....
  const sqln = '...';
  const n = await query( sqln );
  return { a ,b,... ,n};
}
```

Or with async/await you can directly call db.query and use the response

```
 const get_data = async () => {
    const sql1 = '...';
    const res_1 = await db.query(sql1);
    const sql2 = '...';
    const res_2 = await db.query(sql2);
    return { a: res_1 ,b: res_2 };
  }
```

router.js can rewritten as

```
router.get('/edit', async (req, res, next) => {
  const {a:rename_a,b:rename_b and so on}=await db.get_data();
  res.render('view', { rename_a,rename_b and so on })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! But now I struggle with my route.js, the object is undefinied. Do you know how to implement it inside my route.js?

Comment: Are you getting the results from the individual queries?

Comment: Now I get two Objects "[object Object] [object Object]". How can I access the values inside? I tried rename_a[0] but this doesn't work

Comment: umm... do it like this... in router.js Add `const util=require('util');` on the first line.
and rewrite function call to like this `const res = await db.get_data();` and then `console.log(util.inspect(res,false,null,true))` This will let you know what's inside the response.

Comment: I found values but unfortunately they are undefined.

Comment: Are you using `await db.query()` directly. Maybe try it with promises.